# Как создать функцию возвращающую длительность звукового файла?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте. Необходимо создать функцию возвращающую длительность звукового файла.  Файл: http://wooordhunt.ru/data/sound/word/us/mp3/must.mp3

Спасибо.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_duration.asp

Answer (score 1):

Вставим на страницу тег `<audio>`, по умолчанию он не видим. После того, как аудиофайл загрузится (или по крайней мере, его метаданные), можно будет узнать длительность музыки в секундах, прочитав значение свойства **duration**.

```js
document.getElementById("target-audio").onloadedmetadata = function() {
  console.log(this.duration);
}
```

```html
<audio id="target-audio" src="http://wooordhunt.ru/data/sound/word/us/mp3/must.mp3">
```

- [event.onloadedmetadata](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onloadedmetadata.asp)
- [audoio.duration](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_duration.asp)